How can I use dynamic import() in a CommonJS build with NestJS, specifically for the @octokit/rest library?
I'm working with a NestJS project and I need to use the @octokit/rest library, which is an ES module. However, my project is set up to build in CommonJS. When trying to use the library with require(), I run into an error because the @octokit/rest library doesn't support CommonJS imports.
To solve this, I tried using dynamic import() within a CommonJS environment, but after building the project, the import() is still being compiled in a way that doesn’t work with CommonJS. Here's what I tried:
async createRepository(accessToken: string, repositoryName: string) {
    const { Octokit } = await import('@octokit/rest');
    const octokit = new Octokit({
        auth: accessToken,
    });

    const response = await octokit.repos.createForAuthenticatedUser({
        name: repositoryName,
    });

    return response.data;
}


Error encountered:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\...\node_modules\@octokit\rest\dist-src\index.js from C:\Users\...\dist\app.service.js not supported.

How can I ensure that @octokit/rest is imported dynamically in a CommonJS build without causing compatibility issues? Is there a way to make dynamic imports work in this setup, or is there a better approach for using ES modules in a CommonJS project?

check this out: https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/3093

for nodejs v22+ you can just use the --experimental-require-module  nodejs flag. So:
nest start -e "node --experimental-require-module" should be enough
note that Jest doesn't support this flag and so it will fail

It works, but it looks like a hack. However, if I understand correctly, there is no better solution.

other solutions are hacky (like using eval or new Function). But I'd say that the nodejs flag one is the best because nodejs will support it natively at some point
